# Is there a way to customize the look of aliased items?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

By default aliased items such as folders look like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to customize the look?  For instance, I'd like to replace the arrows with something else.  I've looked all over the system preferences but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go sir. http://www.macworld.com/article/1060511/aliasarrows.html. Complete tutorial about changing alias icon, remove and restore it back. Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, exactly hit the spot.